# how to get regular exp from xml schema(xsd)'s complextype?

Tags: c, xml, regex, xsd

How to get regular exp from xml schema? We know that xml schema has definite regular exp. But how to realize it? (e.g. code a program to get regular exp).

Only consider complexType. For example: in xsd, we have:

```
<xs:element name="letter">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="orderid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:element name="shipdate" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Or:

```
<xs:complexType name="lettertype" mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="orderid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <xs:element name="shipdate" type="xs:date"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Find sequence means ",", so the result is "letter (name,orderid,shipdate)"
Result is name regex.

Another example: (if xsd has this:)

```
<xs:complexType name="request">
<xs:all>
  <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="component" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="params" type="varList" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="session" type="varList" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="cgi-data" type="varList" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:all>
```

means complexType's name is "request".
。。。 means 。。。's relationship is "all"（if we express "all" by &）
all is "&", so the result is "request url&component&action&params&session&cgi-data"

Is there someone could help me code a program to realize this function?
Or tell me a algorithm?

I coded a program, but it is too bug, and logically wrong.
Here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<io.h> 
#define MatchMaxLen 69500
void process(char *result,char *str,char *str2,FILE* fp1)
{
if(strstr(str2,"complexType>")) fgets(str2,3000,fp1);
        //strcat(str,   str2);
    char c[5],*pem;
    int m=0;   if(!strstr(str2,"xs:sequence")&&!strstr(str2,"xs:choice")&&!strstr(str2,"xs:all")) return;
    if(strstr(str,"element name=\""))
        {
            pem=strstr(str,"element name=\"")+strlen("element name=\"");

            while(*pem!='\"')*result++=*pem++;//put element name in purec

            *result++=' ';
        }   
    if(strstr(str2,"xs:sequence")) {*result++='(';c[m++]=',';}
    if(strstr(str2,"xs:choice")) {*result++='(';c[m++]='|';}
    if(strstr(str2,"all")) {*result++='(';c[m++]='&';}
    fgets(str2,3000,fp1);
    while(!(strstr(str2,"sequence>")||strstr(str2,"choice>")||strstr(str2,"all>")))
        {
            if(str2,"complexType>") process(result,str,str2,fp1);
    if(strstr(str2,"element name=\""))
    {
    pem=strstr(str2,"element name=\"");
    pem=pem+strlen("element name=\"");
    }
    if(strstr(str2,"element ref=\""))
    {
    pem=strstr(str2,"element ref=\"");
    pem=pem+strlen("element ref=\"");
    }
    while(*pem!='\"') *result++=*pem++;

    char *pmax,*pmin;
    pmin=strstr(str2,"minOccurs=\"");
    pmin=pmin+strlen("minOccurs=\"");
    pmax=strstr(str2,"maxOccurs=\"");
    pmax=pmax+strlen("maxOccurs=\"");
    if(strstr(str2,"minOccurs")&&strstr(str2,"maxOccurs"))
    {
        if(*pmax=='1'&&*pmin=='0')
        {
        *result++=')';
        *result++='?';
        }
    if(*pmax=='u'&&*pmin=='0')
        {   
        *result++=')';
        *result++='*';
        }
    if(*pmax=='u' && *pmin=='1')
        {
        *result++=')';
        *result++='+';
        }
    *result++=c[m-1];
    }

    fgets(str2,3000,fp1);}
    m--;
}

void main()
{
char type[100][20];
char name[100][20];
char res[3000];
char *result=res;
int flag=0;
char *str, *str2,*psp;
char destfname[20];
char *path="E:\\study\\research\\summer\\program\\*.xsd";/*use this when needed in future extension.Well, been used currently*/
char path1[]="E:\\study\\research\\summer\\program\\";
int len;
FILE *fp1,*fp2; 
char string[MatchMaxLen];
char string2[3000];
struct _finddata_t   ffblk;
long done= _findfirst(path,&ffblk);  
do{ /*sprintf(filename,"dtd%d.dtd",i); 
In the future if the filename is not regular or we don't know the exact numbersome day, 
you may need function like _findnext,_findfirst.Well, currently being used*/
strcat(path1,ffblk.name);
if ((fp1=fopen(path1,"r"))==NULL)
{ /* read source file*/
        printf("cannot open file\n");
        exit(0);
}
sprintf(destfname,"IncludeNamexsdRe%s.txt",ffblk.name);
if((fp2=fopen(destfname,"w"))==NULL)
{ /* destination file*/
        printf("cannot open file\n"); 
        exit(0);
}   
char *pem;
int j(0);
int i(0);
while (fgets(string,MatchMaxLen,fp1))
{//first while's purpose is to create the map of name and type      
str=string;
if(!strstr(str,"element name")) continue;// the thing u need to process
i++;
pem=strstr(str,"element name");
pem=pem+strlen("element name=")+1;//pem: pointer of the element name
while(*pem!='\"')//while not the end point """
{
name[i][j++]=*pem++;//put the element name to the name[][]
}
name[i][j]='\0';
if(!(psp=strstr(string,"type="))) continue;
memccpy(type[i],psp+6,'\"',22); 
}
rewind(fp1);//normal process, here we go
char purecomplex[20];
char *purec=purecomplex;
char ctype[20];
char *cotype=ctype;
while (fgets(string,MatchMaxLen,fp1))
{   
        if( strlen( string ) == 0 ) 
            continue;
    str=string;
    if (str == NULL) 
        continue; 
    if( strlen( string ) == 1 ) continue;   
    //printf("%s",string);

    str2=string2;
    if(strstr(str,"<!--")) 
    {
        while(!strstr(str,"-->"))
        {
        fgets(str2,3000,fp1);
        strcat(str, str2);
    //delete useless char
    //printf("%s\n",str2); 
        }
    continue;
    }
    if(!(pem=strstr(str,"element name=\""))&&!strstr(str,"complexType name=")) continue;

    /*while(match(str))
    {*/
        fgets(str2,3000,fp1);
        if(strstr(str2,"annotation>"))
        {
            do{ fgets(str2,3000,fp1);}while(!strstr(str2,"</xs:annotation>"));
            fgets(str2,3000,fp1);
        }

        if(strstr(str,"complexType name=\""))
        {
            char* pt;
            pt=strstr(str,"complexType name=\"")+strlen("complexType name=\"");
    //if(strstr(str,"element name=\"")) pt=strstr(str,"element name=\"")+strlen("element name=\"");

            while(*pt!='"') *result++=*pt++;//if has complextype name, put it in cotype

            *result++=' ';
        }
        process(result,str,str2,fp1);
    }//}
    *result='\0';
    fputs(res,fp2 );
    //fputc('\n',fp2 );

    //printf("%s\n",ffblk.name);
    printf("2===%s\n",string);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}while(!_findnext(done,&ffblk));

_findclose(done);         

}
```

Is there someone could help me code a program to realize this function?
Or tell me a algorithm?

Comment: XSD is XML, don't use regex to do this, rather use an existing xml parsing library.

Comment: not use regex. but take out regex from xsd

Comment: I guess you want to convert XSD to a regular expression. This is impossible in the general case, but might be possible for your specific document. Does it have circular references, like type `X` containing type `Y`, which contains type `X`?

Answer (score 1):

Since every XSD content model can in fact be translated into a regular expression over QNames, and one might want to exhibit this XSD for documentation purposes or for purposes of reasoning about the complex type more conveniently, this question is not quite as quixotic or off-base as some respondents appear inclined to suspect.  At least, not necessarily quixotic or off-base.

But it would be easier to be enthusiastic in helping you solve this problem if you provided a bit more background on why you want to do this and what you hope to do with the results.  If you want to validate documents against the schema, then normally you'll be better off using an off-the-shelf validator.  (It can always be fun to write your own validator instead of using off-the-shelf tools, but anyone in a position to write their own XSD validator won't need help translating XSD content models to a regex-like notation, so I infer that that's not what you're aiming for.)

But enough warnings.  If you really want to do this, for whatever reason, the task is conceptually trivial in a suitable XML-oriented language like XSLT.  I append an XSLT program to illustrate the general approach; it works correctly (as far as I have tested it) on simple cases, but it ignores all the bookkeeping and fiddly details needed for work with real schemas.  It makes no attempt to handle complex-type extension, multi-namespace schema documents, or complex types defined for elements local to another complex type.  And like your samples, it takes the name for the named regular expression either from the complex type being translated or from the enclosing element declaration, which means it will run into trouble if the schema has types and elements with the same local name.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                >

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <!--* Ignore anything that looks complicated *-->
  <xsl:template match="xsd:attribute 
                       | xsd:attributeGroup
                       | xsd:group
                       | xsd:schema/xsd:element[@type]
                       | xsd:notation
                       | xsd:annotation
                       "/>

  <!--* Ignore text nodes (otherwise the output will be
      * inundated with whitespace) *-->
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

  <!--* Top-level elements with local complex types; those
      * we want to handle.
      *-->
  <xsl:template match = "xsd:schema/xsd:element[xsd:complexType]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--* Aha!  A complex type whose content model we want to turn 
      * into a regular expression 
      *-->
  <xsl:template match = "xsd:element/xsd:complexType
                         [xsd:sequence | xsd:choice | xsd:all]">
    <!--* write out the name for the named regex *-->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;&#xA;',
                          @name, parent::xsd:element/@name, 
                          ' ')"/>
    <!--* write out the regex *-->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--* Simple recursive case:  we encounter a model group. *-->
  <xsl:template match = "xsd:sequence|xsd:choice|xsd:all">
    <!--* Parenthesize the group and handle its children. *-->
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>

    <!--* Append *, ?, +, or {min, max}. *-->
    <xsl:call-template name="occurrence-indicator"/>

    <!--* If our parent has further children, 
        * append the appropriate connector. *-->
    <xsl:call-template name="connector"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--* An element in a content model. *-->
  <xsl:template match = "xsd:element[ancestor::xsd:complexType]">
    <!--* Write out the element's name.  We're lazy so 
        * we don't bother with a QName for a local element.
        * Also, we don't recur. *-->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ref, @name)"/>

    <!--* Handle occurrence indicator and connect
        * just as for groups. *-->
    <xsl:call-template name="occurrence-indicator"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="connector"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <!--* Emit the appropriate occurrence indicator for
      * a group or element.
      * Use {min,max}, {min,}, or {n} notation for 
      * non-standard occurrence counts.
      *-->
  <xsl:template name="occurrence-indicator">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(@minOccurs='1' or not(@minOccurs)) 
                      and 
                      (@maxOccurs='1' or not(@maxOccurs))">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@minOccurs='0' 
                      and 
                      (@maxOccurs='1' or not(@maxOccurs))">
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@minOccurs='0' and @maxOccurs='unbounded'">
        <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="(@minOccurs='1' or not(@minOccurs)) 
                      and 
                      @maxOccurs='unbounded'">
        <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@minOccurs=@maxOccurs">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{', @minOccurs,'}')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@maxOccurs='unbounded'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{', @minOccurs,',}')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('{', 
                              @minOccurs,
                              ',',
                              @maxOccurs,
                              '}')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="connector">
    <!--* Emit the appropriate connector, if we need one. *-->
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[self::xsd:sequence 
                  | self::xsd:choice 
                  | self::xsd:all 
                  | self::xsd:element]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::xsd:sequence">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="parent::xsd:choice">
          <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="parent::xsd:all">
          <xsl:text> &amp; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If for some reason you cannot or will not handle the problem in XSLT, then what you have to keep in mind is that you just need to do a normal depth-first traversal of the tree (specifically the XML tree in the schema document's specification of the content model), emitting the appropriate brackets and operators at the appropriate times.

- On each element, emit the appropriate QName.
- On each group, emit a left parenthesis, handle the children, then emit a right parenthesis.
- After each expression (whether element or group), emit an occurrence indicator:  *, +, ?, empty string, or a count operator like `{4}`, `{2,}`, or `{0,4}`.
- Between any two sibling expressions (i.e. after each expression that has a right sibling), emit an appropriate connector:  comma, ampersand, or or-bar.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am studying xslt now to use ur code, can u tell me how to let ur code process xsd numerous glut, not just one by one?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.  If you're wanting to apply the XSLT stylesheet to several XSD schema documents at once, the easiest way varies with your environment, so it's really impossible to advise you without knowing more about what OS and tools you use.  You might want to ask that as a separate question, in any case.

Comment: yes,want to apply the XSLT stylesheet to several XSD schema documents at once ?
I am the new comer in xslt.  so any environment is ok. Do u have some advice for me?